# I have a error trying to insert a public class , 'PlayerCollision' already defines a member called 'OnCollisionEnter' with the same parameter types

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

'PlayerCollision' already defines a member called 'OnCollisionEnter' with the same parameter types"
Is the error i get when i add  public class GameManagement manaGement. line 3,14 and 7,10 are causing issue i can't solve.  H ere a screenshot of the project [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zCwo.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxYyf.png)

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerCollision : MonoBehaviour {

    public PlayerMovement movement;

    public GameManager gameManager;

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collisionInfo)
    {
        if (collisionInfo.collider.tag == "Obstacle")
        {
            movement.enabled = false;
        }

    }

}
```

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gg7RN.png)

Comment: Please include the error as text in your question.

Comment: i put the link https://i.stack.imgur.com/gg7RN.png

Comment: "as text" not "as image".

Comment: Ok i just did some edit

Comment: _"Is the error i get when i add a another public class "_ - what do you mean _another_ public class? You don't already have a class in the same namespace called `PlayerCollision`, do you?

Comment: No i don't it the only one

Comment: Could you add a screenshot with your Project tab with all scripts there? Because on the added by you screenshot Unity clearly says that there is a definition for the class already. Thanks.

Comment: Thhanks everyone i found the problem

Answer (score 0):

On your screenshot you clearly have `PlayerCollision` definition twice. One is in the Project folder **scripts** and another one is outside

Comment: Yes thank to you and everyone i found the error thanks a lot, i shouldn't be coding at 4 am